# Looking for a specific joke about arguments for Meinongianism

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request, existence, being

I remember reading a book (or a paper) some time ago, that had a line somewhat like this:

> There are good arguments for Meinongianism. They just don't exist.

Now, I find this very funny and find myself telling this joke often. But I cannot, for the life of me, recall where I came across this line. If you know of a book or a paper that has this line—or something akin to it, for I might be misremembering—please, do share the reference with me.

A google search did not yield any results, unfortunately. This prompts me to think that I am misremembering the quote. Nevertheless, the idea of the joke seems clear. So, any leads?

Comment: I didn't google and I didn't  bing. Nothing ta report! 

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From what I can tell, you appear to be recalling [this discourse](https://philarchive.org/archive/HOAMMA):

[image]

This was a little bit of trouble to find (I tried Googling "joke about meinongianism" and it gave no results directly, but luckily the disquoted follow-up gave the above result instead).

Comment: Lovely joke, lovely find

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thank you so much! :)